# Need routing help for updating current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, actioncontroller

I have a `/account` page that routes to `users#edit` and the form action is `/users/1`. When there are errors, the rendered page is `/users/1`. How can make the errors render at `/account` again?

If I redirect I lose those errors I need to display.

I suppose if it's a GET then do `users#edit` if it's a PUT then do `users#update`. Is that the right way? How should I write my routes?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a route  for `POST /account` that calls `users#update`:

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/account' => 'users#edit'
post '/account' => 'users#update'
```

Your form can now `POST` to /account and if there are validations errors the rendered view will have a URL of /account.

However this is breaking the RESTful pattern and patterns should only be broken if there's a good reason to break them.